# Time period of a physical pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, moment-of-inertia

Considering a physical pendulum consists of a thin homogeneous rod, is it possible to find the time period without calculating the moment of inertia of the rod?

[image]

Comment: Isn't it $T\propto \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$, by dimension analysis?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my problem. I am talking about a physical pendulum. This is the relation for the simple pendulum, isn't it?

Comment: I would say, up to some dimensionless form-factor, this is what I would expect from a real thin rod. Note, perion $T$ (time) is alsway certain, whereas frequency $\omega$ is not in a general case - due to non-harmonicity of oscillations.

Comment: Sorry, I was late to upload a photo. So, for what '$l$' is in this case?

Comment: I have no idea (and no desire to solve this problem).

Comment: do you mean a relation for T without I?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but it would be equivalent to the simplest method via momentum of inertia. I do not understand why you would like to avoid it.

Comment: If so, can you please explain how, @GiorgioP ? I have already derived an equation for period with moment of intertia. But I want to avoid it (actually, 'parallel axis theorem' is what I want to avoid) as I got a problem that was intended to solve without it.

Comment: @joseph h , Yes

Answer (score 1):

For small oscillations the theoretical period of the pendulum depends on the moment of inertia of the rod and the position of its pivot. For large oscillations there will also be a dependency on the amplitude of the swing.

If the rod is uniform it is not difficult to calculate its moment of inertia.

If you want to avoid using the moment of inertia you could, I suppose, calculate the forces on each small element of the rod and integrate along the length of the rod - but essentially you are still finding the moment of inertia of the rod and using the parallel axis theorem in disguise, just not labelling them as such.

If this is an actual physical pendulum than you can, of course, dispense with theory and simply measure its period by timing, say, ten swings and taking an average.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer and according to your answer the thing I realize is that I cannot ignore moment of inertia. Then,for further clarification, in finding '$T$' of a 'simple pendulum', is moment of inertia used in disguise?

Comment: @ACB In effect, yes. The centre of mass of a simple pendulum is a distance $L$ from the pivot, its moment of inertia about the pivot is $mL^2$, and if you substitute these values in the formula for $T$ for a compound pendulum you get the simple pendulum formula $T =2 \pi \sqrt{\frac L g}$

Comment: A pendulum like this is called a *compound pendulum*. a google search will provide a full derivation of its equations of motion.